# Integration by substitution with bounds

Tags: calculus, integration

I have a quick question here, I was working on integrating this formula over the x-axis and finding the area of the surface revolution.

$y = \sqrt{5-x}$, $3 \leq x \leq 5$.

$$\begin{align}
S &= 2\pi \int_{3}^{5} \sqrt{5-x} * \sqrt{1 + \bigg( \frac{-1}{2\sqrt{5-x}}\bigg)^2}dx \\
&= 2\pi \int_{3}^{5}\sqrt{(5-x) + \frac{1}{4}}dx \\ 
&= 2\pi \int_{3}^{5}\sqrt{\frac{(21-4x)}{4}}dx \\ 
&= 2\pi \int_{3}^{5} \frac{-1}{4} \sqrt{u} \\ 
&= \frac{-\pi}{4} \bigg[ \frac{2u^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}\bigg]^{9}_{1} \\
&= \frac{-\pi}{4} \bigg[ \frac{54}{3} - \frac{2}{3} \bigg] = \frac{-13\pi}{3}
\end{align}$$

When I calculated the bounds in terms of u, I got $u = 21 - 4(5) = \textbf{1}$ and $u = 21 - 4(3) = \textbf{9}$. Does the upper bound stay the upper bound even though it is now a lower number? $\int_{1}^{9} \sqrt{u}du $ or $\int_{9}^{1} \sqrt{u}du$?

The answer is actually $\frac{13\pi}{3}$, a positive number, which I would get if I flip around the subtraction in the brackets.

Answer (score 2):

The $u$-limits must correspond *in order* to the $x$-values. The fact that $du/dx$ is negative is already telling you that you're going backwards on the $u$-interval as $x$ goes forwards.

Comment: Okay, thank you for confirming this.